# Unicode T-SQL like not returning expected all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unicode

I have created a database in SQL Server 2008 R2 and front end in MS Access 2003 which is `.adp` file format. This application uses Devnagari Unicode fonts for labels and data in database.

The back end has a table `tblBookInfo` for storing Unicode data.

When I write a query to find all records starting from particular character then it does not return all the expected records.  The query is as follow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblbookinfo info 
WHERE 
  (Language = 1) AND  
  (Type = 1) AND
  Author LIKE N'क%'
```

It does not return records which have starting character is "कु".  It returns records whose starting character is "क", "कि", "को" etc.

I get Unicode of "क" character i.e. 0915 and "कु" = 0941

If I loop thr' "कु" for Unicode character numbers, I get 0915 then 0941 but like N'क%' does not return records having "कु"

Comment: What data type and collation has the `Author` column ?

Comment: what's the collation used ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean nvarchar(max) data type is used for Author column

Comment: @KamranShahid The default collation is used i.e. "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Comment: I think now you have found your answer Sham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my tests, if `NVARCHAR` data type is used with `Indic_General_100_CI_AI` collation then `LIKE` will returns required results:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT N'क'  UNION ALL
    SELECT N'कु' UNION ALL
    SELECT N'how (strange!)'
) x (Author)
WHERE   x.Author    COLLATE Indic_General_100_CI_AI 
LIKE    N'क%'       COLLATE Indic_General_100_CI_AI
```

Output:

```
Author
--------------
क
कु
```

Comment: +1 for the answer but one quick question please, if he has had collation set on column level would he still need to use the `COLLATE` clause in the `WHERE` clause of this query ???

Comment: According to [SQL Server Collation Precedence](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx) "Explicit [collation] takes precedence over implicit [collation]. Implicit takes precedence over Coercible-default: *Explicit > Implicit > Coercible-default*". If "collation set on column" means a collation defined only on `Author` column using `ALTER \ CREATE TABLE` (`CREATE TABLE dbo.tblBookInfo(... Author NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE ... )` then the answer is no.

Comment: @M.Ali: Happy New Year to you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use the `OR` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblbookinfo info 
WHERE 
  (Language = 1) AND  
  (Type = 1) 
  AND
  (
    (Author LIKE N'क%') 
    OR 
    (Author LIKE N'"कु%') 
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Author NVARCHAR(1000) COLLATE Indic_General_100_CI_AI)
GO

INSERT INTO #TempTable
VALUES (N'क'), (N'कि'), (N'को'), (N'कु')
GO

SELECT Author
FROM #TempTable
WHERE Author LIKE N'क%' 
GO
```

**Result**

```
+--------+
| Author |
+--------+
| क      |
| कि     |
| को     |
| कु      |
+--------+
```